# Error: Unfortunately the app stopped

Tags: android

I am new to Android! I am trying to write raw audio data. Does any one know the reason for
the error. I am getting the following errors also:
           Parent view is not a TextView
           FATAL EXCEPTION: main
           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
           ... 11 more
Thanks in advance

```
 Thanks in advance.


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV = ".wav";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE = "record_temp.raw";
private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
short[] audioData;

private AudioRecord recorder = null;
private int bufferSize = 0;
private Thread recordingThread = null;
private boolean isRecording = false;

int[] bufferData;
int bytesRecorded;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.p1);

    setButtonHandlers();
    enableButtons(false);

    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
            RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING) * 3;

    audioData = new short[bufferSize]; // short array that pcm data is put
                                        // into.

}

private void setButtonHandlers() {
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Start)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Stop)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
}

private void enableButton(int id, boolean isEnable) {
    ((Button) findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
}

private void enableButtons(boolean isRecording) {
    enableButton(R.id.Start, !isRecording);
    enableButton(R.id.Stop, isRecording);
}

private String getFilename() {
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV);
}

public void convert() {

}

private String getTempFilename() {
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    File tempFile = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);

    if (tempFile.exists())
        tempFile.delete();

    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);
}

private void startRecording() {
    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

    recorder.startRecording();

    isRecording = true;

    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            writeAudioDataToFile();
        }
    }, "AudioRecorder Thread");

    recordingThread.start();
}

private void writeAudioDataToFile() {
    byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
    String filename = getTempFilename();
    FileOutputStream os = null;

    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int read = 0;

    if (null != os) {
        while (isRecording) {
            read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

            if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read) {
                try {
                    os.write(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void stopRecording() {
    if (null != recorder) {
        isRecording = false;

        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();

        recorder = null;
        recordingThread = null;
    }

    copyWaveFile(getTempFilename(), getFilename());
    // deleteTempFile();
}

private void deleteTempFile() {
    File file = new File(getTempFilename());
    file.delete();
}

private void copyWaveFile(String inFilename, String outFilename) {
    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    long totalAudioLen = 0;
    long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
    long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
    int channels = 2;
    long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels / 8;

    byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
        totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
        totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;

        // AppLog.logString("File size: " + totalDataLen);

        WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);

        while (in.read(data) != -1) {
            out.write(data);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void WriteWaveFileHeader(FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
        long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels, long byteRate)
        throws IOException {
    // another code

}

private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.Start: {
            // AppLog.logString("Start Recording");
            enableButtons(true);
            startRecording();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.Stop: {
            // AppLog.logString("Stop Recording");
            enableButtons(false);
            stopRecording();
            break;

        }
        }
    }
};
```

}

Comment: why is this `// setContentView(R.layout.p1);` commented??

Comment: You want to uncomment the setcontentview(R.layout.p1) because of this you are unable to get the textview and other widgets so the exception is araising obviously if you remove this then you will not get the exception

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Now With setContentView(R.layout.p1); what do I need in the layout XML?

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate function:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// setContentView(R.layout.p1);

setButtonHandlers();
enableButtons(false);

bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
        RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING) * 3;

audioData = new short[bufferSize]; // short array that pcm data is put
                                    // into.

}
```

As pointed out by @Raghunandan and @Hasnain

setContentView(R.layout.p1); has been commented using //. Now the java file for the activity is unable to find the layout xml file and doesnot know what to show on the screen so the app crashes

Remove the // before    setContentView(R.layout.p1); and it should work

Comment: With setContentView(R.layout.p1); uncommented I am getting the error:

Comment: p1 cannot be resolved or is not a field! What do I need to include in the layout XML file? Thanks

Comment: Here is the logcat messages:

Comment: Some first few logcat messages:

Comment: Update your question to include complete logcat and p1.xml file. (error could be in xml)

Comment: @Raghunandan With setContentView(R.layout.p1); uncommented I am getting the error: p1 cannot be resolved or is not a field - what do I need to add in layout XML file if any? Thanks

Comment: @Simon Marquis logcat messages are too long to paste here! Is there a simple way to paste logcat?

Comment: With setContentView(R.layout.p1); uncommented I am getting the error: p1 cannot be resolved or is not a field - what do I need to add in layout XML file if any? Thanks